# Why does EVP_CIPHER is EVP_aes_256_cbc() succeed when key length is not equal 256bits?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

The code encrypt/decrypt function with openssl library, like following...

```
EVP_EncryptInit_ex( ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)
```

It can work, when the key length is not equal 256 bits(32 bytes).
The key length can be any. Why?

For example, it works fine, and no error received:

```
char key[]="012345678901234567890";
```

Comment: Please add some more context around your question so that we can answer more effectively.

Comment: Why ask why? Why not just do it the right way?

Comment: TL;DR the C language doesn't perform bounds checking (instead it uses this lovely pointer arithmetic) so the implementation of that function just reads 32 bytes starting at the `key` pointer location ... whatever is there. Or it crashes as you're doing something you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does EVP_CIPHER is EVP_aes_256_cbc() succeed when key length is not equal 256bits?

You seem to be asking why you can encrypt using `EVP_aes_256_cbc` when the key is smaller, like 128-bits.

If you supply an undersized key you are reading random bytes/garbage at the tail of the key bytes. The function is reading bytes, but you don't know what they are. You may get lucky on the local machine and be able to encrypt and decrypt. It will almost certainly fail to decrypt on a different machine.

Valgrind should alert you to the problem of reading uninaitalezed [key] memory. Asan should alert about a read in a guard zone.

I don't believe `EVP_aes_256_cbc` pads or expands. Like @Zaph said, always use the correct size. If you need to "stretch" a smaller key into a bigger one, then see [HMAC-based Extract-and-Expand Key Derivation Function (HKDF)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869), which extracts entropy then expands it.